# Visual Studio Online with local TFS 2010 Build Service

Tags: azure-devops

Was wondering if anyone has had success with getting a local TFS 2010 build server to perform builds for a project hosted in Visual Studio Online?

We have some legacy components (and some more recent .NET components) in our build (VB6, NSIS) and we have XP machines running TFS 2010 which can build these (we also have reasons to want to perform the build under an x86 OS).

Moving to Visual Studio Online, we had hoped to be able to keep our existing TFS 2010 build servers (or clone the VMs at least) and just point them at the cloud; however running the TFS 2010 installer and its setup wizard does not seem to work; even after installing TFS 2010 SP1 and the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server Compatibility GDR.

The problem seems to be that TFS 2010 does not recognise MSDN accounts as the credentials for the connection to TFS; I can get as far as entering the URL for our VS Cloud, selecting the project, and then proceeding through the wizard to specify the build controllers and agents, and the user the service runs under, but the verify step then fails saying that the account the build server runs under (I have tried my personal account and Network Service - MSDN accounts are refused) does not have permission within our Visual Studio Online project.

I have seen that other versions of TFS allow a separate MSDN account to be specifies for the Visual Studio Online credential, but even after installing SP1 and the hotfix this does not seem to be supported under TFS 2010.

Online searches for this have been unhelpful.

Does anyone have direct experience of this kind of setup?